# Is that possible to change any gamma distribution to $\Gamma(k=0,\theta=1)$

Tags: statistics

If a random variable $x$ follows a Gamma distribution $\Gamma(k,\theta)$, is it possible to transform the variable and make it follows $\Gamma(k=0,\theta=1)$, like we transfer the variable which follows a Gaussian distribution to Normal distribution through $(x-\mu)/\sigma$ ($\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No.*

(a) All **normal distributions** have basically the same shape: $\mu$ shifts position left or right, $\sigma$ shrinks or squeezes. So one can 'standardize' by transforming to get $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1.$

[This makes it possible to work
most problems involving the normal distribution using printed tables of *one*
normal distribution, the standard normal distribution.]

(b) However, for the **gamma family of distributions**, $k$ is a shape parameter. Look at different shapes in Wikipedia article on 'gamma distribution'. Also, both parameters of gamma must be positive, so $k = 0$ isn't possible (unless you're using some kind of nonstandard parameterization).

[Specific information about a subfamily of gamma with integer and half-integer shape parameters (**chi-squared distributions**) is widely tabled, but most problems involving gamma distributions are solved using software. **Exponential distributions** are also in the gamma family (shape parameter 1), and its CDF is available in closed
form so computations are relatively easy without specialized software or printed tables.]

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually, I'm studying pearson's III, which can be considered as gamma distribution but with a transformation. The solution in wikipedia seems not right, as I draw the pdf using the function of "pearspdf" gets different result from using the function gampdf and the transformations. Maybe it's my mistake...